# Modelling equations based on real life/banking examples?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I go to the bank and the bank offers me a product which I have to invest/deposit $3000 every year and this product promises a return of 4% yearly.

Am I right to model this example using the following equation?
\begin{equation}
\Big(3000 + 3000(t - 1)\Big) \times 1.04^{t}
\end{equation}
where $t \equiv \textrm{time}$
Part $A = 3000$ is the initial deposit I made in the first year
Part $B = 3000(t - 1)$ which is the recurring annual deposit I made after the second year
Part $C =$ Multiply the entire sum by $1.04$ since the returns is 4% and to the power of no. of years

What kind of mathematics does this fall under? Algebra? Statistic? I would like to model such equations especially applicable to insurance (probability?) and investments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial deposit of $3000$ is worth $3000 \cdot 1.04^t$ after $t$ years.  The next deposit is worth $3000 \cdot 1.04^{t-1}$ and so on.  After $t$ years, the total account is then worth $3000 \cdot 1.04^t+3000 \cdot 1.04^{t-1}+3000 \cdot 1.04^{t-2}+\dots 3000$ assuming you have made the final deposit.  You can then sum this [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) to get $3000\frac {1.04^{t+1}-1}{1.04-1}$  Your equation is paying the same interest on each deposit, but the later ones are not in the account for as long.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with my formula?

Comment: All the later deposits are drawing interest for the full term, because they are multiplied by $1.04^t$.  Your first term can be simplified to $3000t$, which is the total deposited.  If you have the account for $10$ years, the money you put in at year $9$ just gets one year of interest added